# Is it possible to update inventory_policy for all products using API in Shopify?

Tags: php, api, shopify, shopify-api

From my PHP application, I want to update the inventory_policy (continue/deny) of all products using API. Is there any way to do so without a loop?

Comment: There is no way you have to do it for each product

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any way to update it at once. Hence, I have updated it one by one. Please have the code below.

```
    public function update_inventory_policy_for_all_item($inventory_policy, $page_info=null){
    $response = $this->do_get("/admin/api/2021-04/products.json?limit=250".$page_info);
            
    if ($response === FALSE)
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    $result_products = $response['body']['products'];
    $headers = $response['headers'];

    foreach($result_products as $shopify_product){
        foreach($shopify_product['variants'] as $variant){
            $variant_id = $variant['id'];
            $data['variant'] = array(
                'id' => $variant['id'], 
                'inventory_policy' => $inventory_policy,
            );
            $this->do_put("/admin/api/2021-04/variants/$variant_id.json", $data);
        }
    }

    if(isset($headers['link'])) {
        $links = explode(',', $headers['link']);

        foreach($links as $link) {
            $next_page = false;
            if(strpos($link, 'rel="next"')) {
                $next_page = $link;
            }
        }

        if($next_page) {
            preg_match('~<(.*?)>~', $next_page, $next);
            $url_components = parse_url($next[1]);
            parse_str($url_components['query'], $params);
            $page_info = '&page_info=' . $params['page_info'];
            $this->update_inventory_policy_for_all_item($inventory_policy, $page_info);
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```